# linux distributed file system over WAN advice

Tags: linux, rhel6, distributed-filesystems

I have a fairly simple (not really) requirement but I've looked at a few solutions and can't find a good solution. I've got a Red Hat EL 6 server environment in my co-location and office, and some linux and windows xp and win7 workstations my office.

The co-location and office do not have a high-bandwidth link.  Let's say it's 5Mbps.

I have a collection of files which are processed by batch jobs at my co-location, but are viewed and edited by workstation users, i.e. the files need to be accessible at both locations in a read-write fashion.

Additionally, some individual files are huge - too big to wait for the file to transfer from the "other" location if needed on-demand.  So a copy of each file should be immediately "synced" to the other location if created/changed.

I've looked at AFS, which is almost perfect, except that the distributed "replica" is always read-only, and re-synchronizing the read-only replicas happens after an administrative command, AFAICT.

I'd prefer, also, for each client (e.g. workstation) to not have to have a large cache, but rather have a server at each site which provides local (subnet) access to the shared FS (maybe re-shares the content using local NFS or samba...)

Is there any such fs available for linux rhel 6?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information above I think you have a similar situation to us. We have a main data center with a few remote offices that need offsite mirroring.

We are using rSync. It works very well.

RSync is a free software computer program for Unix and Linux like systems which synchronizes files and directories from one location to another **while minimizing data transfer** using delta encoding when appropriate. An important feature of rsync not found in most similar programs/protocols is that the mirroring takes place with only one transmission in each direction.

Here is a quick overview and guide
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-use-rsync-transfer-mirror-files-directories.html

You may also want to looking into what ubuntu is doing with their orchestra server. not a direct comparison for RHEL however it is just a compilation of other services rolled into a pre-installed package.

Thomas

Comment: I should have mentioned I have considered rsync, in fact there is a project called lsyncd that I have considered which uses rsync but it directly monitors the filesystem for changes.  However that is pretty brute-force.  If a filesystem will do this for me, I'd much prefer it.

Comment: Rsync is fairly light weight. Usually our update only takes a few seconds to complete. Hope you find what your looking for.

Comment: the main issues with a straight rsync are 1. tons of files (more than 75000) - running rsync every few seconds against 75000 files means statting the files each time - quite resource intensive when almost none of them have changed.  2. bidirectional - it needs to sync both directions.

Comment: The main issue with RSYNC is that it does not detect file moves or renames. So that if you rename a folder with a lot of data, RSYNC will consider that the folder was removed and a new one was added. This would cause a lot of data to be pointlessly transferred over a slow link.

Answer (score 2):

You can try MoozeFS or http://www.xtreemfs.org/
Both can be okay for your needs.

Forget about GlusterFS (bugs, bugs, bugs) and Coda (need bandwidth).
You can also have a look at tahoe-lafs (I never tested it).